# How to looop through a jQuery element array and access data?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.7.2.

I have three checkboxes each with a unique company id. When one box is checked, I want to make a list of company ids created from the boxes that are checked.

```
<input type='checkbox' class='Company' data-companyid='1'> 1<br>
<input type='checkbox' class='Company' data-companyid='2'> 2<br>
<input type='checkbox' class='Company' data-companyid='3'> 3<br>

// SET BY CLASS
$Company = $("input.Company");

// GET COMPANY LIST 
function getCompanyList() {
    var len = $Company.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         var CompanyID = $Company[i].data("companyid");
         alert(CompanyID);
    }
}
$Company.change(getCompanyList);​
```

For some reason, I am having trouble accessing the company id via the data method in the loop.  I have lots of examples of my own code where I do this sort of thing, but I can't get this one work.

What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/Msc95/

Comment: `$Company[i]` gets the HTMLElement, you should be using `$Company.eq(i)`.  And the code in your jsFiddle is quite different from what you posted here...

Comment: I have been updating the fiddle. Oops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not accumulating the individual company ID's into any sort of data structure.

The easiest way to return an array of values from an array of (checked) elements is to use jQuery's `.map` function:

```
function getCompanyList() {
    var companyList = $Company.filter(':checked').map(function() {
       return $(this).data('companyid');
    }).get();
    alert(companyList);
}
```

The `.get()` call is necessary to turn the result of `.map()` into a plain array.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/zfUXj/

Comment: I have never used the map method. That looks really easy though.

Comment: @EvikJames FYI - `map` comes from functional programming languages such as LISP and Haskell.  It transmogrifies one array into another array, by applying the supplied function to each element of the original array.

Answer (score 2):

Why not something like this, and put them in an array?

```
var checkedCompanys = new Array();
 $('input.company:checked').each(function() {
     checkedCompanys.push($(this).data("companyid"));    
  });
```

Good luck

Comment: this is exactly what `.map()` is designed for - no need for `push`

Comment: @Roko you've unnecessarily re-evaluated the selector instead of re-using `$Company`

Comment: Good explanation on why to use []... I'll try map and get too. Thanks

Comment: +1 @Alnitak :) my bad! http://jsfiddle.net/aGZCG/1/ I used initially `[]` (Cause I always do, but re-copying the code I forgot to change to it)